# The importance of the structural morphism of a projective variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

In scheme-theory, "The projective $n$-dimensional space over $k$" is defined as $\mathbb P^n_k:=\text{Proj}(k[T_0,\ldots,T_n])$. Moreover $\mathbb P^n_k$ is endowed with a structure of variery over $k$ thans to a morphism $f:\mathbb P^n_k\longrightarrow\text{Spec}\, k$.

> Is there a canonical choice of $f$?

Formally if I choose a another morphism $g$ from $\mathbb P^n_k$ onto $\text{Spec} \, k$, then I get a "different" projective space (as projective variety)!

---

**Example:**

Suppose an imaginary theorem which says that there are only $100$ curves (up to isomorphism of varieties) with a morphism (ie. morphism of $k$-schemes) onto $\mathbb P^1_k$. Then can I use any structure of $k$-scheme on $\mathbb P^1_k$ to construct one of such morphisms? To be more precise If $\alpha:X\longrightarrow\mathbb P^1_k$ and $\beta:Y\longrightarrow(\mathbb P^1_k)'$ are two morphisms of curves where $\mathbb P^1_k$ and $(\mathbb P^1_k)'$ differ only in the structural morphim, then can I say that  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two of the $100$ morphisms described in the imaginary theorem?

---

Comment: Is the "standard" map $k \to k[T_0, \dots, T_n]$ canonical? I would say yes.

Comment: @Hoot, it is canononical only if you want it to be. If K has automorphisms, there are alternatives, for example.

Comment: Canonical doés not really mean anything.

Comment: I'm not saying that there aren't other maps (precompose with any any automorphism of $K$, as you say). But it seems to me that when you write down $k[T_0, \dots, T_n]$ there really is a distinguished one. I'm starting to get dizzy.

Comment: Anyway, I think when you say "morphism of $k$-schemes $f\colon X \to Y$" then you usually have fixed structure morphisms for $X$ and $Y$ in mind, and you're not writing them down because you don't want to. The condition seems less useful otherwise.

Comment: @Hoot: your standard map, although indeed canonical,  does not yield the required canonical morphism. The difficulty is that in the latter morphism there is a mixture of the Proj and the Spec constructions. Fact is that $Proj(k)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I should have said more: I've got a map $k \to k[T_0, \dots, T_n] \to k[T_0, \dots, T_n]_{T_i}$ that lands in the degree zero piece, and I thought those glued together to give the structure map; I could do this for any homogeneous element of positive degree so it doesn't feel like a choice has been made. Is that what you mean? I wouldn't pretend to know more than you do about these matters.

Comment: Dear @Hoot: Yes, although your first comment was maybe a bit too crisp, your new comment above is completely correct and  indeed perfectly describes the construction of the required map (but you must take the degree zero part of your localization at the powers of the $T_i$'s.

Comment: Kudos and +1 to Dubious for not taking the discussed morphism for granted. Of course this was to be expected, given his pseudonym :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a canonical map  $\: \mathbb P^n_k \to \operatorname {Spec(k)}$ for $k$ an arbitrary ring but strangely, even if $k$ is a field,  it cannot be defined in an elegant functorial way but is defined by a rather clumsy glueing procedure.  More precisely:

For every homogeneous polynomial of positive degree $f\in k[T_0,\cdots ,T_n]$ we get the open subset $D_+(f)=\operatorname {Spec(k[T_0,\cdots ,T_n]_{(f)})}\subset \mathbb P^n_k$ and a scheme morphism $D_+(f)\to \operatorname {Spec(k)}$ dual to the ring morphism $k\to k[T_0,\cdots ,T_n]_{(f)}$ (beware that $k[T_0,\cdots ,T_n]_{(f)}$ is the degree zero component of the $\mathbb Z$-graded ring $k[T_0,\cdots ,T_n]_f$).
The open subsets  $D_+(f)$ for varying $f$ cover $\mathbb P^n_k$ and the morphisms $D_+(f)\to \operatorname {Spec(k)}$ are mutually compatible,  glueing to the required morphism $\: \mathbb P^n_k \to \operatorname {Spec(k)}$
[We may restrict ourselves to the subcovering $(D_{+}(X_i))_{0\leq i\leq n}$ of $\mathbb P^n_k$ obtained by only taking the $n+1$ homogeneous polynomials $f=T_i$, at the cost of being slightly less canonical].

**Remark**
The Proj construction although quite powerful is difficult and full of traps.
The present question attests to the  subtlety of this construction, all the more so that many textbooks give it a very crisp treatment and for example don't even mention the canonical morphism investigated here.

Comment: Dear @Georges Elencwajg, your answer is clear (as usual) but I  have another small trouble: Consider a field automorphism $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(k)$ and construct the base change of $\mathbb P^1_k$ through $\text{Spec}(k)$. We obtain a "strange" $\mathbb P^1_k$ that we call $(\mathbb P^1_k)'$ where the structural morphism is different from the one you have described. I don't understand if this $(\mathbb P^1_k)'$ is still "the projective line"  or not (look my example in the question)!

Comment: If my "imaginary theorem" of the $100$ curves is too stupid think at the Shafarevich conjecture (Parshin-Arakelov theorem). It claims that there are a finite number of fibered surfaces over $\mathbb P^1_k$ with a certain property. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two fibrations respectively over $\mathbb P^1_k$ and $(\mathbb P^1_k)'$, can I consider them as "two fibrations over the projective line"?

Comment: Dear Dubious, yes $(\mathbb P^1_k)'$ is still  the projective line over $k$ **provided** you endow it with the new  canonical map to  the new Spec (k). In other words what is canonical is not the naked scheme $\mathbb P^1_k$ but the **morphism** $\mathbb P^1_k \to Spec (k)$ . To fully understand these extremely subtle considerations my advice would be to first study what happens under a general base change $Spec(k')\to Spec(k)$ and then specialize to the case of an isomorphism.

Comment: Is the map $(\mathbb P^1_k)'\longrightarrow \text{Spec} k$ coming from the fibered product (base change along $\sigma$), the "canonical morphism"? This is the main problem.

Comment: Yes! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is music for my ears!

Comment: One more comment: you said the canonical morphism cannot be defined in a functorial way, but I think that there is a way if $k$ is an infinite field of characteristic $0$. $\text{Spec}\,k$ and $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb Z}$ are in an unique way two  $\mathbb Z$-schemes. Therefore one can obtain $\mathbb P^n_k$ as the base change $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb Z}\times_{\text{Spec} \mathbb Z} \text{Spec}\, k$ and the structural morphism is given thanks to the fibered product.

Comment: Dear Dubious,this is indeed an ingenious remark:+1. It also works for a completely  arbitrary field $k$ since there is a unique morphism $Spec (k)\to Spec(\mathbb Z)$. Actually **all** schemes are $\mathbb Z$-schemes in a unique way...